# What is the recommended way to build MSI packages in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Last year I heard that Installer Projects were going away and we should be switching to Windows Installer XML. Whatever happened with that?

So you know where I'm coming from, support for TFS-based buil machines is very important to me. I know Installer Projects kinda-sorta work with TFS, but they have issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, WiX-in-the-box for Visual Studio 2010 didn't happen for what appear to be political reasons (?).  I'd still recommend using WiX though, it's the least worst MSI-authoring option out there.  There's a learning curve though.

Answer (score 0):

IronRuby uses Wix, but that requires upkeep and scripts. I haven't looked into [parrafin](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/10/21/wix-a-better-tallow-paraffin.aspx) or anything like that yet, but the mix of a Parrafin (like) script and WIX would probably work well.